# Create Exit Handler from DLL (`atexit` or `msvcrt!__dllonexit`)

Tags: c, winapi, dll, msvcrt, dll-injection

I'm trying to create a mechanism to workaround the loader lock so I can run arbitrary code only having control of `DllMain()`.

I've had some success, see here:

Demo app loads library: `LoadLibraryW(L"test.dll");`

DLL:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void func() {
    // Spawn calc.exe (can't do this from DllMain but we can here)
    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    wchar_t app[5] = { L'c', L'a', L'l', L'c', 0 };
    CreateProcess(NULL, app, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);

    // We can even load libraries from here so loader lock does appear to be gone

    // MessageBox... this crashes in msvcrt!__dllonexit (why!?)
    // Pretty deep into the call stack to creating the message box it happens (there's only one thread)
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"hi", L"hello", 0);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        atexit(func);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Please, can you help me, why am I getting that error when creating a message box? There appears to be a competing `msvcrt!__dllonexit`, but I'm not sure how to utilize it (the code) or what I should do.

Microsoft's docs say calling `atexit()` in a DLL should work, but according to my tests, it will work for some things and not work for others:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/onexit-onexit-m?view=msvc-170

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/dllonexit?view=msvc-170

Comment: You aren't *"bypassing"* the loader lock. You're merely installing a function to be called when the program terminates. There's no guarantee about the modules that are still loaded when your code runs. Trying to *"run arbitrary code"* from an `onexit` handler is inevitably going to fail.

Comment: @IInspectable That's what I thought too but if you create an `atexit()` handler from the EXE (not DLL) it works fine and I can create message boxes, etc. And I've checked to make sure all modules are still loaded so it's not that (`!address` in WinDbg)

Comment: @IInspectable You're right, I changed it to "workaround". Should've been more specific.

Comment: Possibly your DLL  gets unloaded before the function runs?

Comment: @user253751 That's not it, my DLL is still loaded. I should say also that the crash in `msvcrt!__dllonexit` is what I got one time when I called some other WinAPI function. But actually the error for this (I think I mixed them up) is an exception in `ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParamter`. Does anyone know what that exception really means in this context? I also want to note that another function that fails in `func()` is `ShellExecute()` (its library is loaded, checked that).

Comment: If you need arbitrary code to run *some time* after `DllMain` ran, why not just `CreateThread`? If nothing else, at least you no longer take a dependency on the specific CRT copy used by the DLL. As for the specific idea that you were to be able to run *"arbitrary"* code from an `onexit` handler, that's just not true: [During process termination, the gates are now electrified](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100122-00/?p=15193). `ShellExecute`, in particular, touches so many systems (library loader, COM infrastructure, ...) that failure is almost to be expected.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried `CreateThread`, it seems to work and I get the thread ID DWORD back but when I look in the threads tab it wasn't created and nothing actually starts executing. I put a `__debugbreak()` in the thread start function but it's never run and I'm not sure why. That blog is over a decade old and I just tried again using `onexit()` in the EXE (not DLL) calling both `ShellExecute` and `MessageBoxW` and both calls from there work perfectly. Now if only the same could be same about the `onexit()` from the DLL...

Comment: `atexit()` is standard library C function so for portability reasons it wouldn't really be acceptable for MS to let it to be that flaky (but maybe it was at one point or still is to some extent).

Comment: A thread created from `DllMain` doesn't start executing immediately. There's still a `DllMain` call with `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` pending. All that aside, it would be a good idea if you explained the *problem* you are trying to solve. So far this all reads like you have subscribed to a particular solution, that's unlikely to actually be a solution. Probably just another instance of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: `atexit` typically runs inside the loader lock, too. ("We can even load libraries from here so loader lock does appear to be gone." - the system doesn't stop you from loading libraries from inside the loader lock. It's not a good idea, and can crash, but the system doesn't stop you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some reverse engineering work and it turns out that there are two different types of `atexit` (or `_onexit`) in Windows. First is the Windows loader `atexit`, this is what's used if you run `atexit` from a DLL by default and it is run under loader lock. Second is the CRT `atexit`, this is what's used if you run `atexit` from an EXE by default and it is **not** run under loader lock.

Our goal now is simple, call the CRT `atexit` from our DLL and when the process exits we can do as we please. Here's the code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h> // For CRT atexit functions
#include <shellapi.h> // For ShellExecute

#define DLL
#ifdef DLL
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#define EMPTY_IMPL {}
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#define EMPTY_IMPL
#endif

// Put any necessary exports here
EXTERN_C API VOID ExampleExport(VOID) EMPTY_IMPL;

VOID atexitHandler(VOID) {
    // Verify loader lock is gone:
    // !critsec ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock (as shown in: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140808-00/?p=293)

    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"calc", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Message", L"Test", 0);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Catch both normal exit and quick exit cases (just in case)
        _crt_atexit(atexitHandler);
        _crt_at_quick_exit(atexitHandler);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I've confirmed that this works when our DLL is loaded at runtime (i.e. `LoadLibrary`) or implicitly at load-time. Also, CRT `atexit` handlers run before Windows loader `atexit` handlers, so we're all good on that front.